# How to access asp:Image from Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, servercontrols

I got an asp:Image in my server-markup like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Img1" runat="server"/>
```

Now, I want to find this img in my javascript, but seem to run into the problem of ASP.Net obfuscating my names. The client-markup will look something like this:

```
<img id="ctl00_Content_Img1"/>
```

I imagine this is because everything is inside a form-element called 'Content', which is quite normal I guess? :)

Any pointers on how to access this from javascript?

[EDIT] I was thinking if there's an easy way to change my javascript "servertime" to search for the obfuscated id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can get a server control's client side id by using it's ClientID property like that :

```
<script>
var imgID = '<%= Img1.ClientID %>';
var imgObject = document.getElementById(imgID);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew it was something simple :P

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a client reference of the Id generated on the server-side with the ClientID property:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('<%= Img1.ClientID %>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to put the two previous answers together:

```
var img = document.getElementById('<%= Img1.ClientID %>');
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the `document.getElementById` function.